# Google App Engine - Configure app to always deploy in beta

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, beta

I have an app which must always be deployed using [`gcloud beta app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/) because it uses Google's Memorystore and this requires Serverless VPC Access which is in beta.

If I were to accidentally deploy my app using just `gcloud app deploy` it would break it.

I want to eliminate this risk by (hopefully) configuring `app.yaml` to always deploy to beta.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there in no way to configure this in the app.yaml file of your application. You can see the parameters to add in app.yaml [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

Additionally, there is no way to set this up automatically from the gcloud command, and in the future this feature should be added to the production [gcloud app deploy command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) so you should not need to set this up any longer.

What comes to mind if you want to automate this is for you to create an alias for the beta command and use that to deploy the application, something like the alias shown [here](https://gist.github.com/orevial/1985a1f72eceb34b5f3d399f7ca3c08d).

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, the `app.yaml` is part of what is being deployed by the command, it does not select the command.

To avoid deployment errors just make a small wrapper script with the exact deployment command and all its args and invoke that instead. Eventually using absolute paths as invoking the command in the wrong directory is also a common mistake :)